# background color shows up only when i touch the text

Tags: java, android

Here is a code snippet

```
int bgColor = Integer.parseInt(summaryReportObj.backgroundColor, 16);
lv0.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
```

The bgColor is blue and shows up only when I touch the text.
I want the color to show all the time.
When I set background image it displays just great.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is lv0 ??? a label? a JPanel? a frame? we need more info here.

Comment: It's almost certainly a "ListView" ...

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is correct and lv0 is a ListView then you should try setting your color on the actual list view items you're putting into the list.